# what siddur/prayer book is this?

Tags: prayer-book

What prayer book / siddur, is this? (publisher)

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_16079_576.pdf

The english transliteration isn't my thing but I like how at the bottom it says mourners recite kaddish drabbanan,..that they recite it after mishnayot.  A lot of siddurim are missing even that rather pertinent instruction that mourners recite kaddish drabbanan.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the Chabad siddur, [Siddur Tehillat Hashem](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0826601529), or one of the machzorim. It is published by Kehot in Brooklyn and you can find it in any Chabad schul or home, as it follows the nusach created by their first rebbe (see forward to the siddur).

Comment: do they do one with english instruction without transliteration?

Comment: IIRC the translator is British; in Hataras Nedarim most translate "ואין אני תוהא ח״ו" as "I do not regret, G-d forbid"; Tehillat Hashem has "I do not rue, Heaven forfend"!

Comment: @barlop, they do, although it also lacks translation. I will link it below in a minute

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Siddur-Tehillat-Annotated-Tehillim-Hardcover/dp/B008RAF65Y/ref=sr_1_10?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1438000944&sr=1-10&keywords=tehillat+hashem+siddur

Comment: That looks strikingly similar to Artscroll's formatting. Did Kehot borrow the format?

Comment: @ShmuelBrown, that's been my supposition for many years. I've seen other siddurim do this as well, although in my own typography, I've attempted to avoid becoming an ArtScroll clone.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I know that the OU put out a series of _machzorim_  (pre OU Press years) with the commentary of Rav Soloveitchik and made a point of highlighting the fact that they used the Artscroll format.

Comment: @ShmuelBrown, K'hal is through ArtScroll. See artscroll.com